# How to define Typescript interface where one property an array's value at a variable property name?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
export interface Contact {
  "email": string;
  "first_name": string;
  "last_name": string;
  "phone"?: string;
}
```

I want to add a new attribute to this interface that represents the following attribute:

`field[field_name, default_value] = value`

My interface would chance to something like:

```
export interface Contact {
  "email": string;
  "first_name": string;
  "last_name": string;
  "phone"?: string;
  "field[field_name, default_value]": any;
}
```

I tried:

```
export interface Contact {
  "email": string;
  "first_name": string;
  "last_name": string;
  "phone"?: string;
  "field[string, any]": any;
}
```

Also tried defining a different interface:

```
export interface Field {
  [key: string, value: number]: any;
}

export interface Contact {
  "email": string;
  "first_name": string;
  "last_name": string;
  "phone"?: string;
  field[Field]: any;
}
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: What is `field[field_name, default_value] = value`? It is not an array or an object. Are you looking for `field = [{"field_name": "default_value"}, {"field_name": "default_value"}]`?

Comment: It's one of any number of fields on a third party library. I basically want to create this object using their API, and one of the fields can be set using something like:

`field[%FIELDNAME%,0] = value`.

Since I am using typescript, I need to create a property for this, but it's supposed to be dynamic, e.g. `field[AGE, 0] = 20` or `field[PHONE, 0] = "609-999-9999"`, etc.

Comment: What's the `0` for?  Why not just `field[Age] = 20` ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for, and the syntax `field[n, v]` probably doesn't mean what you want it to.  The value of `n` will be evaluated and then discarded, and you'll end up with `field[v]`.  Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish without using that syntax?   Good luck!

Comment: so i figured out that since the key can be any string, I can just use `[key: string]: any`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by defining an [index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html):

`[key: string]: any`

This works for my case since the key part can be any string, and the value can potentially be any type.